# How to get the path of android folder being shown after the opening android phone in Explorer?

Tags: android

I have been searching over the StackOverflow how to get specific paths, but I only found solutions about External Storages (SD cards). I need to create and read data from internal storage (in-built memory), but I can't reach the proper path. 
I want to create folder programatically in this folder shown in a picture [image: Folder where I want to create my own folders programatically] 
so the user of my app can put there .csv files used to import their contents to database, and get .csv file exported from database.
I have tried my own attempts but they did not work.

So my question is: How can I take a path of the folder shown in a picture for creating my desired folder and files there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only found solutions about External Storages (SD cards)

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices.

> I want to create folder programatically in this folder shown in a picture

That is showing [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), as is viewed from a Windows desktop or notebook by means of a USB cable or other MTP-based connection.

There are [a variety of ways of working with external storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage).

Comment: Thank you, these articles gave me an awser to my question!